# How do I set the PS1 (prompt) macOS Monterey 12.6.2

Tags: terminal, prompt, ps1

How do I set the PS1 (prompt) in terminal on my macbook pro using Monterey 12.6.2.
I am trying to have the prompt in terminal to display my current directory. In terminal and on the command line, I used PS1=\W and variations of that, but it is not working as it did in other version of the macOS.

I would like to see my prompt displaying my current working directory when I am using terminal.